# add multiple unique header from SQL server in android

Tags: android, sql-server

I am retrieving some data from SQL server in listivew android:-

```
 connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    lstcountry = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstcountry);
    String querycmd = "SELECT  user_mst.name+'--'+dept_dispatch_code as grpname,tl_no,ltr_nm_addrs, ltr_sub,'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=cg.nic.in/raipur/TLMIS/upload/'+ fileUploading as fileUploading\n"+
            "FROM  letterRecord INNER JOIN user_mst ON user_mst.user_id=letterRecord.dept_dispatch_code\n" +
            "WHERE  (ltrStatus_code = '1')  order by dept_dispatch_code asc ,CAST(tl_no AS int) desc";
    try {
        Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(querycmd);
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arraylist3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arraylist4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            arraylist.add(rs.getString("tl_no"));
            arraylist1.add(rs.getString("ltr_nm_addrs"));
            arraylist2.add(rs.getString("ltr_sub"));
            arraylist3.add(rs.getString("fileUploading"));
            arraylist4.add(rs.getString("grpname"));
        }

        String[] mStringArray = new String[arraylist.size()];
        mStringArray = arraylist.toArray(mStringArray);

        String[] mStringArray1 = new String[arraylist1.size()];
        mStringArray1 = arraylist1.toArray(mStringArray1);

        String[] mStringArray2 = new String[arraylist2.size()];
        mStringArray2 = arraylist2.toArray(mStringArray2);

        String[] mStringArray3 = new String[arraylist3.size()];
        mStringArray3 = arraylist3.toArray(mStringArray3);

        String[] mStringArray4 = new String[arraylist4.size()];
        mStringArray4 = arraylist4.toArray(mStringArray4);

        MySQLMyAdapter2 as = new MySQLMyAdapter2(CollectorDetail.this, mStringArray, mStringArray1,mStringArray2,mStringArray3,mStringArray4);
        lstcountry.setAdapter(as);

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(CollectorDetail.this , e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And the output is below:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ5FS.png)

and my table is below:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYmmh.png)

in my list view there is one field as grpname which is repeating in every unique row i want only 1 unique header.
How cane i do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** :

Use Sectioned `RecyclerView`
https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview
https://github.com/IntruderShanky/Sectioned-RecyclerView

**Solution 2** :

Compare current item text with previous item text, if both are same, remove that header text from current view.

**Note** : To use any of the solution you must have data arranged in a group, you cannot have a data like A,A,B,A,A,C,B it should be like A,A,A,A,B,B,C